# Writing an if statement depending on an attribute of an agent to command agents of a different agentset

Tags: netlogo, agent-based-modeling

I am trying to make an agentset do something, if an agent(of a different agentset) has a particular shape.

Here, if the shape of a particular

- ghost (say Ghost 1) is circle,
- then all rabbits are supposed to move forward 1. (<-This is the
  intended behavior)

where

- **ghosts** are `agentset A`
- **rabbits** are `agentset B`

I have tried along these lines:

```
ask rabbits
[
 if (shape ghost 1 = "circle")
  [
   forward 1
  ]
]
```

For this code I get,

> "Expected a closing paranthesis here."

with a highlighter on ghost.
I'm aware that this code is wrong but I can't think of how else this should be written to get the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will (I think - can't test) get the syntax correct:

```
ask rabbits
[
 if ([shape] of ghost 1 = "circle")
  [
   forward 1
  ]
]
```

but you also have an ordering error and will have every rabbit check the shape of chost 1. I think what you really want is:

```
if ([shape] of ghost 1 = "circle")
[ ask rabbits
  [ forward 1
  ]
]
```

Comment: Perfect! It does the required job.
I have "ask rabbits" placed in the beginning as there are many more commands running that lead to this if statement. I tried to ask the question in the most simplified way as I can to avoid irrelevant complexicity.